# Javascript : how to get return value

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I need to return value from my getItemData function, like this :

```
function getItemData(success, error) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var ListeEtabScol = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Etablissements Scolaires');
    var ItemEtabScol = ListeEtabScol.getItemById(123456);

    clientContext.load(ItemEtabScol, 'Title', 'Adresse', 'Commune');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        function() { success(ItemEtabScol); }, error
    );
}

var test = getItemData(
    function(item){
        return item.get_item('Adresse'); //this is ok, adress is returned
    },
    function(sender, args){
        alert('Erreur : ' + args.get_message());
    }
);

console.log(test); //test is undefined :-( what's wrong ???
```

but my test variable is ever undefined.
Any idea of my mistake ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Comment: That link is partially relevent, but you never return anything from the function anyways. You'll need to return a Promise of a value or something

Comment: @RickRiggs That won't help anything.

Comment: you **can not** return a value from some async code, because you have no idea wether/when some value is available. Check out the link in the first comment and/or Promises.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I tried jquery's deferred function and Promise with then() without success :-(
That's why I want to use callbacks... any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Question has already been asked and answered many times...

[How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function) (concise)

[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) (detailed)

Simply put, you need to use a callback (a function that will be "called back" when what you asked for is completed):

```
function onComplete(a){ // When the code completes, do this
    console.log(a);
}

function getFive(callback){ 
    var a;
    setTimeout(function(){ //just here to have asynchronicity
         a=5;
         callback(a); 
    },10);
}
```

and usage would be:

```
getFive(onComplete);
```

Answer taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6847754/9368855

Comment: You should flag as duplicate if you know it has been already answered

Comment: I can't... (not enough reputation I guess? kinda new to Stackoverflow)